# Soldering PCB with nickel strip

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, soldering, soldering-iron-station, nickel

I am looking to design a PCB with pads that are wide. I want to use these pads for soldering nickel strips. I couldn't find any source of whether someone has already attempted this.

1. Is it possible? What are the challenges?
2. I want to know what kind of soldering iron I should use? (Power rating and soldering leads.)
3. Could it possiblly cause damage to the other electronic components present on the PCB?

Comment: MentorGraphics PADs to design a wide PCB or you are designing a PCB that has wide pads? I think probably the latter but, it's better to ask. Regards your questions I don't think anyone can recommend a soldering iron for two reasons (1) requests for product recommendations are off-topic for this site and (2) no details means it cannot be answered even if someone ignored (1). Also, your other two questions are too open-ended and therefore solicit opinions so, item (3) is that questions soliciting opinions are off-topic too.

Comment: >100W, giant chisel tip. As big as will fit, even if it's bigger than the strip.

Comment: The good news: tin/lead solder adheres to nickel very well. Don't know about lead-free solder. You need a soldering iron big enough to heat your nickel strip above the melting temperature of solder. Small strip easy, big strip harder.

Comment: Depending on the size, you could attach it with nuts and bolts instead of solder.

Comment: I have found that solder does not wet out nickel very well. You should probably use a special flux to solder to nickel, and that flux may require thorough cleaning afterward. But soldering to nickel is definitely possible.

Comment: You might want to pre-wet those nickel strips with solder. Be careful of de-laminating copper from PCB if those strips are rigid and/or thick...try to do little flexing.

Answer (score 3):

Nickel (and nickel alloys, like stainless steel) cannot easily be tinned (wetted with soft solder) using fluxes  intended for copper.   Liquid (not paste) acid flux (I've used Nokorode
type) intended for steel and stainless steel is effective.

Apply a small amount of flux to the nickel, heat the fluxed area with wire solder applied, and when the solder sticks, rinse off any flux that remains with water.  Acid flux may affect your soldering iron tip, so you may want to keep a second iron for the non-nickel operations, that never encounters acid.  Never apply acid flux to a copper printed wiring board, it will corrode the copper.  Wash immediately.

A wipe with flux, and dip in a solder pot, is a good way to tin many items quickly.

The now-tinned nickel surface can be soldered just as  you would solder a tinned copper wire.  Nickel strip is also weld-able, before tinning, but soft solder is not compatible with weld temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible? What are the challenges?

The biggest problem with soldering large wires or metal pieces to a PCB is getting the piece up to temperature. All of the metal and PCB traces around the solder joint must be hotter (or at least as hot) than the solders melting temperature ( SAC305 is 217C) A large strip of metal will wick away (conduct) heat from the area being soldered and also make a mini heatsink and help the air to convect away the heat.

> I want to know what kind of soldering iron I should use? (power rating
> and soldering leads)

Anything with a big tip, but another thing you may want to consider is also a hot air gun, even warming the PCB to a safe temp of 60C or 70C can go a long way to keeping the area that you want to solder up to temperature. Usually when I solder large pieces, chips or modules, I also use a hot air gun to help warm the PCB (usually on the backside) this makes it much easier to get the solder over a broad area up to melting temperature.

> Are there any possible damages to the other electronic components
> present on the PCB.

Yes, if you get the PCB too hot (above 130C) it may burn or warp (especially for long periods of time). Most components have an absolute max temperature of 125C (except when soldering for a brief amount of time for a few seconds to tens of seconds as indicated in the packages datasheet). So the trick is whatever you are soldering to do it fast, the longer you stay above the rated temperatures is more risk to damaging a part.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply. I will take your suggestions and from others and will implement them.  It was really helpful!!!

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had success with relatively narrow nickel strips (3mm).  If the strips don’t tin easily then it may be use to tin them before applying them to the PCB.  On the PCB itself it would be wise to add some vias around the pad to reinforce the copper and minimise the danger of tearing the pad off the board.  If these are untented then they are likely to fill with solder which reinforces them further and significantly reduces their resistance.